# How to translate flutter's intl .arb files after the phase out of Google Translate Toolkit?

Tags: flutter, google-translator-toolkit

> Google Translator Toolkit will not be available after Dec 4, 2019.

Flutter's internationalization package, [intl_translate](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_translation), is based on .arb files which can only be translated with Google Translate Toolkit.

I searched a lot but was not able to find an alternative to translate arb files.

How are you planning to support your Flutter app internationalization without Google Translate Toolkit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "attranslate" is a new tool to translate ARB or JSON-files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate It can translate automatically, but it also provides first class support for manual translations.

Answer (score 2):

[Localizely](https://localizely.com/) supports .arb files and offers Free plan.
You can also use it free of charge for open source projects.

Via [Flutter Intl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) extension for VS Code and [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) plugin for Android Studio, you can easily integrate your projects from IDE with Localizely platform.

Comment: Are you affiliated?

Answer (score 0):

My localization files have following format

```
{
    "string_key" : "string_value"
}
```

which is actually valid JSON format and valid ARB format as well.
So I save them as 'locale-en.json', 'locale-ru.json' and edit using [TransPlug](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8230-transplug) plugin for IntelliJ.

At the same time my flutter project has symlinks to these files with names 'strings_en.arb', 'strings_ru.arb' which are used for generating i18n.dart using [Flutter i18n](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n/) plugin for IntelliJ